# What is the markup for a group identity element

Tags: symbols

It is conventional in Mathematics to use a `1`, often subscripted, as a symbol for the identity element of a group. Is there a symbol for that, or do I have to resort to something like `{\large 1}_G`?

Comment: you can't use size commands in math, you could use `\text{\large 1}` but do you want it large, I'd have thought `\mathbf{1}_G` was more common?

Comment: How about `\mathbb{1}` from `bbm` package? I have seen that symbol being used as group unity element as well as unit operator

Comment: `\mathbb{1}` usually denotes the identity map. A plain `1_G` or `e_G` seem  fine.

Comment: I like the `\mathbbm{1}` (also ? bbm package) better, but this denotes usually a unit matrix and not an abstract identity element, very often put down as `e`.

Comment: I've always used simply `1`.

Comment: \mathbb{1}_G using amssymb came out strange; I'll try \mathbf{1}_G.